# jQuery Tokeninput with "Combobox" functionality?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tokeninput

I'm using [Loopj Tokeninput plugin](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) and I would like to know if anyone has implemented the [jQuery "combobox" functionality](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) in it? or something similar? The scope is to allow for displaying all the data from a local source by clicking an "arrow down" or just by clicking in the input field just like a dropdown menu (but allowing to narrow it down when typing something...). If so, could anyone share how to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey there is no method predefined to do that in tokeninput plugin.. However we can alter the plugin itself to achieve what you need.
I did some alter to plugin .Do the same change in your jquery.tokenput.js file and see if it works. Open the js file.Search for

> var input_box

Now goto .focus(function(){}) part of it and and replace it with this.

```
if (settings.tokenLimit === null || settings.tokenLimit !== token_count) {
       if (settings.local_data) {
           setTimeout(function() { run_search(''); }, 5);
       } else {
           show_dropdown_hint();
       }
```

Search for **function run_search(query)**. 
go to else if part of the function and replace it with below one.

```
else if (settings.local_data) {
                // Do the search through local data
                var results ;
                if(query==''){
                    results= settings.local_data;
                    }
                    else{
                    results= $.grep(settings.local_data, function(row) {                        
                    return (row[settings.propertyToSearch].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) == 0 || row[settings.propertyToSearch].toLowerCase().indexOf(' ' + query.toLowerCase()) > -1);

                });
                }
```

We are using onfocus of that input box to return the whole list when the box is in focus and query is empty.if query is not empty then it will search for that query.

Additionally, if you wants to show a scrollbar in the search results box, you should modify the css of "div.token-input-dropdown" in the token-input.css file as follows:
  - Eliminate or Comment: "overflow: hidden;"
  - Add: "max-height: 150px;" (or whatever max height you want the box to have)
  - Add: "overflow: auto;"

Comment: Thanks @ashirvad-singh! This seems to work! I just revised a bit your answer to allow for default plugin behavior when loading results with Ajax, and modify the css to allow for a scrollbar to show up in the search results box (to limit the height of the box). As soon as you are clear with my edits, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @Ashirvad : hey your code is working great. Two things I worry are i) the up and down arrows are not working with the dropdown. ii) when we click in box because of the code added all the results are showing up. What should be done for these two.

Answer (score 8):

[`Chosen`](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) is exactly what you need.

> Chosen is a JavaScript plugin that makes long, unwieldy select boxes
>   much more user-friendly. It is currently available in both jQuery and
>   Prototype flavors.

Comment: Thank you @joao. I did not know about the Chosen plugin. It looks awesome and definitely does what I'm looking for. I might end up using it. However, I would like to see if one can easily use the Tokeninput plugin for this purpose, since I'm already using it in my form for autocomplete inputs that require ajax calls (and I would like to prevent using another plugin with its own css to customize).

Comment: Thank you Joao Silva. I didn't know about this control until read your answer.