# How to show dropdown before searching in tokeninout.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tokenize, jquery-tokeninput

I have a predefined object of data in the format:

```
c = [{
    "id": "856",
    "name": "House"
},{
    "id": "1035",
    "name": "Desperate Housewives"
},{
    "id": "1048",    
    "name": "Dollhouse"
},{
    "id": "1113",
    "name": "Full House"
}]
```

I need to load show this result onfocus of the input box, and also the search should be working

```
jQuery('#id').tokenInput(c, {
    theme: "facebook",
    preventDuplicates: true
});
```

Any idea on the properties of tokenInput for doing the same?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Tokeninput with "Combobox" functionality?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028269/jquery-tokeninput-with-combobox-functionality)